# NHibernate count of items in xml mapping

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Is there a way in NHibernate to map the result of a count query to a property on a class?  I'd like to do this in the XML mapping.

I know I could formulate this via code (either with a construct that actually queries the count, or by cheating, doing the full query, and counting the resulting items), but it would be nice if I could write some short SQL or HQL and jam that into my XML mapping, somehow.

A concrete example.  My DB has these tables -

```
Entry
  Id
  BodySummary

Comment
  Id
  EntryId
  Body
```

I want to get a summary of entries.  For each of the entries, I want to get the comment count (and body summary).

FYI: I've omitted irrelevant parts of my DB, like authors, entry title/body, timestamps, etc.  This of course should have no bearing on the part of the query I am asking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with HQL. But here's how to do it with SQL:

```
<class name="Entry" .... >
  <id>
    //ID Strategy
  </id>
  <property name="BodySummary" />
  ...
  <property name="CommentCount" formula="(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Comment c WHERE c.EntryId = Id)" type="Int32" />
</class>
```

Important to note:

1. Wrap the sql in parenthesis - it will error if it is not wrapped
2. This is not HQL - you have to use the database column/table names not your mapped classes/properties
3. Provide a return type so NHibernate knows how to map it back to the property

You will probably want to make this a readonly field but this is the basics of how you would map it.

The resultant SQL would be something like this:

```
SELECT          this_.Id                as Id11_0_,
                this_.BodySummary       as BodySummary10_11_0_,
                (SELECT COUNT(* )
                 FROM   Comment c
                 WHERE c.EntryId = this_.Id) as formula0_0_
FROM     Entry this_
```